# How to write truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

our teacher gave us two expressions

> (A+B')(A'+B')

and

> (p+q')->(p^q)

How can I set up a truth table for these.

I couldn't figure out the first problem, but on the second problem i have this:
[image]

But this is just what was copied from the book and I don't understand it. On the right side what are the 0 and 1 values representing. Is it representing that the whole statement is true or false?

Comment: When you have $p=0$ and $q=0$ on the left column of the table, this  refers to the situation that both $p$ and $q$ are false. When you have $p=0$ and $q=1$, this  refers to the situation that $p$ is false and $q$ is true, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So '+' means "or" ($\vee$) and '^' means "and" ($\wedge$) (btw, in latex, these two symbols are \vee and \wedge, respectively).  You make the table of every piece of the equation:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| p | q | !q | p or !q | p and q | (p or !q) --> (p and q) |
------------------------------------------------------------
| T | T |  F |    T    |    T    |            T            |
| T | F |  T |    T    |    F    |            F            |
| F | T |  F |    F    |    F    |            T            |
| F | F |  T |    T    |    F    |            F            |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Remember, $p \rightarrow q$ is true when either $p$ is `false` or both $p$ and $q$ are `true`.  So this means the expression $(p \vee \neg q) \rightarrow (p \wedge q)$ is only true when either both $p$ and $q$ are `true` or when $p$ is `false` and $q$ is `true` (which makes the hypothesis of the implication `false`).

Comment: The picture shows $(p\vee \lnot q)\to (p\wedge q)$.

Comment: OK...that's a pretty simple fix.